# Using RequireJS with XRegExp: "XRegExp is not defined"

Tags: javascript, regex, requirejs, xregexp

I am using RequireJS with `order.js` and I need to use `xregexp-all` to include in RequireJS. Here is my code sample:

```
require(["order!xregexp-all","order!../myscript"],function(XRegExp) {console.log(XRegExp.version)});
```

Here is the console log that returns me the version. But I could not able to use the XregExp in `myscript.js` it gives me following Error:

> "XRegExp is not defined"

How can I use XRegExp in the rest of the code?

Comment: Have you define `xregexp-all` ?

Comment: What version of RequireJS are you using? What version of XRegExp? Please show how you configure RequireJS. (Edit all this into your question.)

Comment: My version of require js is RequireJS 0.27.1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the second argument of require is a function, with a parameter, that you named XRegExp. Outside this context it does not exist.
What you can do is create a global variable, and assign it in that context to the XRegExp:

```
var myRegExp;
require(["order!xregexp-all","order!../myscript"],function(XRegExp) {
  myRegExp = XRegExp;
  console.log(XRegExp.version)
});
//... rest of your coude...//
console.log(myRegExp);
```